# How callMe function works in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `callMe` in following code. But my output is coming as undefined.if I remove last `console.log(myGreeting);` from functopn then it printing "Hello" How it works and why its coming `undefined.`

```js
var myGreeting="Hello";
function callMe(){
console.log(myGreeting);
var myGreeting = "HI";
console.log(myGreeting);
}
```

Comment: You aint calling `callMe` function, are you? No logs...running the snippet.

Comment: have you called this callMe() or not  on any event??

Comment: I did not. And that'w why I asked how it is work. I was not clear with msdn doc.

Comment: so it will console like first will be undefined and then second will be Hii

Comment: does it run like it?

Comment: This suppose to be like that. Now I get to know first `greeting` is undefined.

Comment: what is the reason for downvote. I could'nt find this on SFO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120477/discussion-between-shanky-singh-and-bunker-boy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has 2 scopes, local and global. Local Scope is the every `function's scope`. If you have 2 variables with the same names which one is in the `funciton's scope`, it will first access to it's `scope`. So in your example the outer `myGreeter` is hidden for the `function`.Any variable that is defined as **`var`** works with `hoisting`. So your code translates into this one

```
var myGreeting="Hello";

function callMe(){

   var myGreeting; // which is undefind

   console.log(myGreeting); // undefined

   myGreeting = "HI";

   console.log(myGreeting); // HI
}
```

In which every variables with `var` keyword and functions declaration are moved to the top of the function.

For more see here 
https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

Comment: @shanky singh see here

Comment: yes I am reading the doc. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan In call function why we need to declare variable. Can not we access global variable.

Comment: @shankysingh Of Course we can, in your code you have declared inside the function. You can remove the inner's declaration and your code will work as you want

Comment: That I declare after first `console.log(myGreeting); ` . You declare that one before which is coming as undefined. Any how I am getting undefined.

Comment: @shankysingh it is `hoisting`.Every var declarations are moved to the top of the function

Comment: @SurenSrapyan `hosting.` I am missing something. OK. I guess I need to study bit more the doc which you share. I accept your answer once I completely understood the things.

Comment: Thanks for answer.